# My Maven projects's pom.xml throws a dependency error

Tags: java, xml, maven

I've been trying to create a projec tusing maven to mamage my imports, however, there is one part of the code that is throwing me an error that I'm unable to fix:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It throws "Missing artifact org.junit:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.1Java(0)"

To my knowledge junit is already installed on my computer and it still doesn't work.
Sorry if I'm missing smth rly obvius, I'm not great with xml.

Comment: Fix the groupId <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>

Answer (score 1):

I suspect groupId mentioned in pom.xml is in-correct. Try this

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: still throws the same error

Comment: post your pom.xml